# Windows 7, copy configuration

Tags: windows-7, clone

I configured a new laptop in our office and installed everything. In the next days, we will get another another laptop of same model. So, am I able to copy/save the whole configuration, so I don't have to install everything new on the other laptop?

I created a WIM image from the whole HDD, but how can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

A WIM image can be used on a WDS Server if you have one available? If you do I can go into more detail of rolling this out. If not I dont believe the WIM file is much use (although there maybe some third party software to use it). Remembering that with that WIM file Windows has to have been SysPrep(ed) before it will be usable so all the SID's are wiped, etc. If you haven't SysPred(ed) it then I suggest you have a little read up on that.

Comment: Sysprep isn't necessary for imaged based deployments. SIDs needing to be wiped is a myth:http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx

Comment: @jmp242 Sysprep IS necessary or at least a good idea. http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2009/12/03/sysprep-machine-sids-and-other-myths.aspx

Comment: I'm sure Microsoft recommends sysprep, and I wouldn't strongly argue against using it. I'm saying that it certainly isn't necessary. I know that empirically - I've deployed literally hundreds of Windows 7 computers without sysprep from a "gold image". I do name changes via scrip after deploy. They all work fine - for as long as 4 years on the oldest deployments.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you don't need a WDS server to play around with WIM files or deploy them. WIM files are very powerful and can be used from WDS, to SCCM, to bootable VHD's and custom bootable DVD's. I'm going to talk about the later here as it seems to be a best fit for you but if you get a chance, take a ponder at bootable VHD's!

Basically what you could do, seeming this is just one laptop to another so the shop (workplace) sounds small is that you can create and name a new WIM file as "install.wim" and place the file onto a ISO that is the Windows media! Here is a full process of doing such a task http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825131.aspx#bkmk_5.

Even though the link talks about Windows 8 and Windows 8.1, the same principals apply in Windows 7 and possibly, but don't take my word for this, Windows Vista SP2.

Also take a read at this too so you don't get caught out by it. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2009/04/13/error-message-windows-cannot-access-the-required-file-d-sources-install-wim-when-replacing-install-wim-with-custom-install-wim.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do this much simpler by using something like clonezilla. Acronis Backup (the business version) has a Universal Restore tool that can even restore to many different hardware types.

If you want to use Windows tools, you're probably best served by using wbadmin to create a backup on an external disk or network share, and then boot with the Windows 7 DVD, select "repair my computer" and "Use an image I previously created". This also lets you select (in a more difficult way) different drivers if necessary.